# Create array from output of command that is newline delimited and contains spaces

Tags: arrays, bash

There's a lot of similar questions, but I couldn't find one that fixed my problem. It's possible I don't know what to google.

I'm trying to create a pair of arrays and then loop through both by index. The contents of the array is generated from this command:

```
$ cat small | grep -Po "(?<=Query: ).+$" | grep -v "use"

select count(*) from batting_small
select count(*) from batting_small_parquet
select count(*) from batting_small_parquet_stats
select yearid, count(*) from batting_small_parquet group by yearId
select yearid, count(*) from batting_small_parquet_stats group by yearId
select min(hr), max(hr) from batting_small
select min(hr), max(hr) from batting_small_parquet
select min(hr), max(hr) from batting_small_parquet_stats
...
```

But making an array like this

```
queries=( ` cat small | grep -Po "(?<=Query: ).+$" | grep -v "use" ` )
```

Splits by word and not by line. How can I split by line?

Comment: Looks like you analyze mysql slow log files, for that purpose there is a special routine `mysqldumpslow` in mysql package, I think it can do much what you want.

    mysqldumpslow --help

Comment: They are not mysql logs, but thanks for a possible alternative

Answer (score 1):

use the `mapfile` bash builtin, and redirect the grep command from a process substitution:

```
mapfile -t queries < <( grep -Po "(?<=Query: ).+$" small | grep -v "use")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-z` option in `grep` to produce a NUL terminated output and then use process substitution in a `while IFS= read -d ''` loop:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r line; do
   echo "<<$line>>"
done < <(ggrep -zPo '(?m)(?!.*use)(?<=Query: ).+$' small)

<<select count(*) from batting_small>>
<<select count(*) from batting_small_parquet>>
<<select count(*) from batting_small_parquet_stats>>
<<select yearid, count(*) from batting_small_parquet group by yearId>>
<<select yearid, count(*) from batting_small_parquet_stats group by yearId>>
<<select min(hr), max(hr) from batting_small>>
<<select min(hr), max(hr) from batting_small_parquet>>
<<select min(hr), max(hr) from batting_small_parquet_stats>>
```

Change `echo "<<$line>>"` line to your actual code.

Also note use of `(?m)` to enable `MULTILINE` mode in regex and a negative lookahead `(?!.*use)` to avoid another `grep -v`.